# How to retrieve do JomSocial Activity Link based on activity ID?

Tags: jomsocial

I have this situation:

```
<?php 
foreach ($activities as $activity){

    // user
    $user  = CFactory::getUser( $activity->actor );
    $name = $user->getDisplayName();
    $link = CRoute::_('index.php?option=com_community&view=profile&userid='.$activity->actor);

    //likes 
    $likes = count(explode(',', $activity->like));
    echo $activity->id. ' - '.JHtml::Date($activity->created, 'd-m-Y H:i:s', true) .' por <a href="'.$link.'">'.$name.'</a>';
    echo ' <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> '.$likes.'<hr>';
}
?>
```

I need the post (activity) link based on activity ID.

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
CRoute::_('index.php?option=com_community&actid='.$activity->id)
```

for example:
instead

```
JHtml::Date($activity->created, 'd-m-Y H:i:s', true)

'<a href="'.CRoute::_('index.php?option=com_community&actid='.$activity->id).'">'.
JHtml::Date($activity->created, 'd-m-Y H:i:s', true).'</a>'
```

Comment: If this answer resolved your issue, please mark your answer with the green tick.